# "Literal does not match the format string" error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ora-01861

When I try to execute the below code it gives me an `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` error.

I am trying to copy some of the column values from `customer1_details` table to `customer2_details` table. The columns datatype which I am trying to move is `TIMESTAMP(6)` for `TIME_REGISTERED`, `DATE_DISCHARGED` columns and the datatype for `DATE_OF_BIRTH` column is `DATE`

```
    try
    {
        Connection conn=Address.getOracleConnection();  
        int id = 1;     
        Date dob = null;
        Timestamp timereg = null,datedischarged = null;

        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TIME_REGISTERED,DATE_DISCHARGED,DATE_OF_BIRTH from customer1_details WHERE customer_id = '"+id+"' ");
             if(res.next())
             {      
                 timereg=res.getTimestamp("TIME_REGISTERED");           
                 datedischarged=res.getTimestamp("DATE_DISCHARGED"); 
                 dob=res.getDate("DATE_OF_BIRTH");     
             }              

            String sql1="INSERT INTO customer2_details(TIME_REGISTERED_3,DATE_DISCHARGED_3,DATE_OF_BIRTH,customer_ID) "
    + "VALUES('"+timereg+"','"+datedischarged+"','"+dob+"','"+id+"') ";

        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.close();       
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {            System.out.print(e);           }
```

It will be more helpful if anyone provides the answer `without using INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... statement`.

Comment: Why not do it as one statement: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`?

Comment: I think the error means that the date format that Java uses when concatenating to a string doesn't match the syntax that Oracle understands when parsing dates. If you want to do it this way, you need to format the date explicitly in the way Oracle understands it.

Comment: My actual query is a bit complex i am gathering data from multiple tables and then inserting that data in the customer2_details table.All other columns do not give any error except these three columns as provided above in my question

Comment: You should still be able to do it in one statement, by using a join.

Comment: Ok  i will try it @barmar

Comment: If you want some help constructing that join, you'll have to show the actual query.

Comment: But i am copying the values from column of one table to another so the date format which i fetch from the columns of first table and store it in the variables must be same as what oracle supports. Do i still need to format it again ? Can u please show how to format it if necessary @Barmar

Comment: You're not copying it as a string. You're assigning to Java variables declared as `Date` and `Timestamp`. When you then concatenate them with `"VALUES('"+timereg"')"` you get whatever format Java chooses to use, not the Oracle format. Does Java jave a prepared statement feature? If so, that would also solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can do it in one statement with a query like:

```
"INSERT INTO customer2_details (TIME_REGISTERED_3,DATE_DISCHARGED_3,DATE_OF_BIRTH,customer_ID)
SELECT TIME_REGISTERED,DATE_DISCHARGED,DATE_OF_BIRTH, customer_id
from customer1_details WHERE customer_id = '"+id+"' "
```

Comment: I accept the answer is correct. But please read my edit to the question.Is it possible to do without using INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... statement

Comment: Probably. But since I don't know Java, I can't write it without doing more research. If you know Java you should be able to figure it out easily based on the advice in my earlier comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by passing your Date and Timestamp variables as Strings to the insert statement.

When you insert or update Date or Timestamp values, there is a default format in which you can pass those values as strings. What you pass is java's idea of how to convert Dates and Timestamps into strings. These two don't seem to match.

Your best bet is probably to use bind variables, then the framework should take care of that.

An Alternative would be to use Oracle's to_date() function, where you can specify the format string. You would then define a format string which considers java's way of representing dates as strings. However, I am not sure if the java representation depends on the locale. If so, you would have to write you own date_to_string() method, which always returns dates in the same format, or your program may work on some computers, but not on others with a different locale.

And finally you can do an insert-select which bypasses the java layer entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Read the timestamps as strings with getString();

OR call toString() in your java Timestamp object instances.

```
String sql1="INSERT INTO customer2_details(TIME_REGISTERED_3,DATE_DISCHARGED_3,DATE_OF_BIRTH,customer_ID) "
    + "VALUES('"+timereg.toString()+"','"+datedischarged.toString()+"','"+dob.toString()+"','"+id+"') ";
```